# Current user context when sending action cable message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, actioncable

I have a rails application with REST api built using active model serializer.

To make things simple - let's say i have a `Post` serializer that returns `title` of the post and `is_voted` with `true` or `false` value depending on if currently logged in user voted on this story or not.

```
  attribute :is_voted do
    voteable_ids = current_user.account.votes.where(voteable_type: 'Post').map(&:voteable_id)

    voteable_ids.include? object.id
  end
```

And it all works great so far but things gets tricky when i want to notify javascript client about changes in the `Post` record.

Let's say the title changed and i want to send a actioncable event about that:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'updates_channel', {
  event: 'posts.updated',
  data: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(post).to_json
}
```

The thing is - when sending event like that, i don't know what's the `current_user` at this point as it's triggered by the backend. Or basically can be triggered by other user. But if i'm getting this right, actioncable endpoint knows who's the `current_user` so, theoretically, it could be injected.

I was thinking - is that possible to kind of inject the current_user to that serializer in some sort of actioncable middleware? I can authenticate users to my action cable endpoint using `identified_by :current_user` but i have no idea how to use it in that scenario.

Another idea is to just send the event about post being updated just with the post id. Later, on JS side, i can just fetch that specific post using regular REST api and update the view - but that sounds like a super unoptimal solution.

Comment: I don't get why current user is not available at the time you generate the event.